# How to add placeholder inside table cell asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, placeholder

I want to add placeholder2 inside Registration table under Image Preview Column. I am getting image path value but i m not able to display the preview of that image. The image path is stored in the database.

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = this.GetData();
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append("<div class='container'>");
        html.Append("<div class='table-responsive'>");
        html.Append("<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>");
        html.Append("<thead>");
        html.Append("<tr style='color:Crimson'>");
        html.Append("<th>First Name</th>");
        html.Append("<th>Surname</th>");
        html.Append("<th>Birth Date</th>");
        html.Append("<th>Birth Month</th>");
        html.Append("<th>Birth Year</th>");
        html.Append("<th>Gender</th>");
        html.Append("<th>ID Card Path</th>");
        html.Append("<th>Image Preview</th>");
        html.Append("<th>Approve \\ Reject</th>");
        html.Append("</tr>");
        html.Append("</thead>");
        html.Append("<tbody>");
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr style='color:RoyalBlue'>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");

            }
            string path = row["IDCardUpload"].ToString();

            html.Append("<td>");

            Image img = new Image();
            img.ImageUrl = path;
            img.Width = 100;
            img.Height = 100;
            PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(img);

            html.Append("</td>");  

            html.Append("<td align='center'>");
            html.Append("<button type='button' class='btn-success btn-s'>Approve</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;");
            html.Append("<button type='button' class='btn-danger btn-sm'>Reject</button>");
            html.Append("</td>");

            html.Append("</tr>");
        }
        html.Append("</tbody>");
        html.Append("</table>");
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
        html.Append("</div>");
        html.Append("</div>");
    }
}

private DataTable GetData()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName,Surname,BirthdayDay,BirthdayMonth,BirthdayYear,Gender,IDCardUpload FROM Registration"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to display image thumbnail under image preview column. please help.

using this code my output is like this

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRMR3.png)

Comment: It looks like you have chosen the most difficult, complicated way to accomplish a task.   You could use a GridView, or an asp:Table, or even raw HTML markup and it would be simpler.  And you can still customize the final table.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have some *certain* controls in **HTML** and other are added using placeholders or **.net classes**. You can use [TableCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), TableRow and other classes in System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace to write code against  classes. Either way, you need to be consistent either using  all HTML or using all classes.

However, if you need to use inline html then you may also use the image HTML tag (Img) in your tablecell.

```
<img src="yourimagePath.gif" height="50px" width="50px">
```

Here, you may add the **src** dynamically from the Database value and add it inside the td element.